# GeoPackage (GPKG) with custom style and spatial area

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, style, geopackage, sqlite

With Qgis 3, with the tool available in "Processing" "Layer packaging", package layers within a GeoPackage database by saving the style. But unless I am wrong, it does not allow to customize the export to a custom spatial Area of Interest (for example, area of the canvas).
Conversely, via the "layers panel", you can right-click -> export as save in a GPKG, to a personalized spatial footprint. But at this level, I don't feel it's possible to keep the style.

Would there be a tool in Qgis combining these 2 possibilities? To package in a GPKG a selection of layers, to save not only the layers but their styles defined in the same personalized extent (for example the extent of the canvas?)?